# Get Authorization token to call API

Tags: angular, azure, azure-api-management, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to call the API that I created by [following these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad), I got to the point where I can call the API from Developer Portal using the JWT token.

Now I'm confused, how will the angular client app get this JWT token in order to call the API?

Currently, users of the angular app are in the Active Directory (same AD that was used in directions to set up the API).  The sign-in process is done through [MSAL library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular). When I try to get the token by calling [acquireTokenSilent](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/2de03e0818346993bdcdbcf0bb5cee7aeb56d8e0/lib/msal-angular/dist/msal.service.d.ts#L38) and try to call the API using this token, I get 401 error.

How do I get the correct JTW token from the angular app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you grant permissions for your client app with the permissions you exposed in the api app, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#grant-permissions-in-azure-ad).

Then in the [`consentScopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular#acquire-a-token) , use the api scope of your api, you can find the `Application ID URL` in the `Expose an API` page of your API App, e.g. something like `api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api_usage`

```
consentScopes: [
        '<Application ID URL>/scope'
      ],
```

When you get the token, use `["<Application ID URL>/scope"]` for the `scopes`.

```
const requestObj = {
    scopes: ["<Application ID URL>/scope"]
};

this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
    // Callback code here
    console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Fore more details, refer to [Tutorial: Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from an Angular single-page application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular). In this doc, it calls the MS Graph, to call your own api, change the scopes and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may not able to get the token using acquireTokenSilentAsync in the case where the session has already expired or within grace period. when it failed to get the token, call acquireTokenAsync will redirect the user to enter their password to sign-in.

```
authContext
    .acquireTokenSilentAsync(x,y,z)
    .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
           // process authResponse
    })
    .catch(() => {
      authContext
        .acquireTokenAsync(x,y,x,"")
        .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
           // process authResponse
        }).catch(() => {
           //do things
        }).finally(() => {
           //do things
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey Joko, thank you for the suggestion, however, I get the 401 error right after I sign in. Usually, the tokens don't expire right away.  Welcome to StackOverflow!